# redisson-spring-boot-starter - TTL issue when Cache is created using RedissonSpringCacheManager

Tags: spring-data-redis, redisson

In a simple spring boot starter web project, I am using redisson-spring-boot-starter. I have enabled caching by @EnableCaching on my Spring boot application class.

I have configured a cache with TTL of 60000 milliseconds i.e. of 1 minute, and using it with RedissonSpringCacheManager. I am using this cache in @Cacheable on a service method which takes some argument.

There are two things now:

1. When I check redis via redis-cli, I can see that method call results were successfully cached in redis, but type of cache is hash. When using RedisCacheManager, results are store in key-value pair(like demo_org_cache::1, demo_org_cache::2 etc). **Why results are cached in hash when RedissonSpringCacheManager is used?**
2. The TTL set doesn't work correctly when using RedissonSpringCacheManager. I made 3 method calls with different arguments at 0 seconds, 20 seconds and 50 seconds. All results were cached. However, 1st entry was evicted at 64th second, 2nd at 98th second and 3rd at 130th second. As per TTL, 1st entry should have been evicted after 60 seconds, 2nd after 80 seconds and 3rd after 110 seconds. **If I use RedisCacheManager, entries are evicted exactly at correct time. What is the issue when RedissonSpringCacheManager is used?**

Below is my code:
**pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.14</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>cahingdemo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>cahingdemo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.redisson</groupId>
            <artifactId>redisson-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.18.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**SpringBootApplication class:**

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.redisson.api.RedissonClient;
import org.redisson.codec.JsonJacksonCodec;
import org.redisson.spring.cache.CacheConfig;
import org.redisson.spring.cache.RedissonSpringCacheManager;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cache.CacheManager;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
public class CahingdemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CahingdemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager(RedissonClient redissonClient) {
        Map<String, CacheConfig> config = new HashMap<>();

        CacheConfig testCacheOrg = new CacheConfig();
        testCacheOrg.setTTL(60000);
        config.put("demo_org_cache", testCacheOrg);

        RedissonSpringCacheManager redissonSpringCacheManager = new RedissonSpringCacheManager(redissonClient, config);
        redissonSpringCacheManager.setCodec(JsonJacksonCodec.INSTANCE);
        return redissonSpringCacheManager;
    }
}
```

**Service Class:**

```
package com.example.demo.service;

import org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.example.demo.dto.OrganizationDetails;

@Service
public class OrganizationService {

    @Cacheable(cacheNames = "demo_org_cache", key = "#id")
    public OrganizationDetails getOrgDetails(Long id) {
        OrganizationDetails orgDetails = new OrganizationDetails();
        if (id == null) {
            id = 100l;
        }
        orgDetails.setId(id);
        orgDetails.setName(id + " :: Demo Org");
        orgDetails.setEmail("support@demoorg.com");
        return orgDetails;
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
package com.example.demo.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.demo.dto.OrganizationDetails;
import com.example.demo.service.OrganizationService;

@RestController
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    private OrganizationService orgDetailsService;

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public OrganizationDetails test(@RequestParam(name = "orgId", required = false) Long orgId) {
        return orgDetailsService.getOrgDetails(orgId);
    }
}
```

**For reference, below is my SpringBootApplication class when I use RedisCacheManager instead of RedissonSpringCacheManager:**

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.redisson.api.RedissonClient;
import org.redisson.spring.data.connection.RedissonConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cache.CacheManager;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCacheConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCacheManager;
import org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer;
import org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.RedisSerializationContext;

import com.example.demo.dto.OrganizationDetails;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
public class CahingdemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CahingdemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    public RedissonConnectionFactory redissonConnectionFactory(RedissonClient redissonClient) {
        return new RedissonConnectionFactory(redissonClient);
    }

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager(RedissonConnectionFactory redissonConnectionFactory) {
        Map<String, RedisCacheConfiguration> cacheConfigurations = new HashMap<>();
        cacheConfigurations.put("demo_org_cache",
                RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
                        .serializeValuesWith(RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair
                                .fromSerializer(new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<>(OrganizationDetails.class)))
                        .entryTtl(Duration.ofMillis(60000)));

        return RedisCacheManager.builder(redissonConnectionFactory).cacheDefaults(RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig())
                .withInitialCacheConfigurations(cacheConfigurations).build();
    }
}
```